# Can I use git to merge two svn trees?

Tags: git, svn

I am working on a project that is using svn and I've been working on a separate branch that now I want to merge with a an existing branch.  I am getting lots of errors that I can't solve with svn.

I am wondering if I can install git locally to try to perform the merge with git and then use the git-svn bridge to push back the merged changes to the svn repo.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go)**

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. It seems like this is a workflow question so this is the appropriate forum.

Comment: I doubt that git is any better at a huge merge than SVN is.

Comment: Have a look at [`git imerge`](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge), it's built specifically for huge merges.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone your SVN repo to a local Git repo (including all the history), and let Git do the merge:
`git svn clone ${SVN-URL} ${target-directory}`